# Problems that might be faced in rebuilding earlier MSVC version built code to newer version

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Would like to ask a general question.

Would be trying to scope the difficulties and effort require to build a code (which was earlier build in MSVC 2005) in MSVC 2010.

I am not using any MFC, just using plain C++?

What would be the problems that I might face? Would appreciate any help to also highlight considerations that I should look into

Tthanks

Comment: You just go build, the project!! lets see

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft keeps a list of breaking changes to the compiler on each major release, you can find that list here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.100).aspx.  If you are going from 2005 to 2010 then you will want to look at both 2008 and 2010 changes.